# How to do integration testing with front-end code and API in separate repositories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, integration-testing

Any strategies for doing this? We have a Rails codebase that is currently fully integrated (same app serves up JS assets as does the back-end heavy lifting), but are thinking of extracting the two out into separate services, each in their own git repository and running on separate servers.

I'm planning on unit/acceptance testing the API with a small ruby HTTP client that will also act as documentation for the API endpoints, and the JS front-end (Brunch.io, Backbone, Chaplin) will have unit/acceptance testing internally as well... but I feel like I should be writing cucumber tests that integrate the two together, right? Where do those cukes live? In which repo?

Appreciate any insight here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In a general sense, if you have code that is for both your server and your client, then the "right" place to keep it depends on which side of your app is more central or "heavier": the client or the server.

That being said, from the way your describe things in your question, it kind of sounds you consider the Rails app "primary".  For instance, you mention that you currently have "JS assets" integrated/being served by your "Rails codebase" ... not Rails assets being served by your JS server ;-)

So that answers things on the theoretical level, but I also think it makes sense to put the code in your Rails codebase for a practical reason: Cucumber is a Rails tool, not a JS one.  You might use it to test some non-Ruby code, but ultimately it's being run by Ruby.

I don't know for sure, but I suspect you'll create headaches for yourself if you try and put your Cucumber specs in your JS codebase, then try to run them from your Rails codebase.  Plus, that really tightly couples the two codebases: to run your tests you need both codebases on your testrunner vs. if you keep the Cucumber stuff in Rails-land your test runner could just have your Rails code, and it could run against a different server that has your JS code.

So ultimately it sounds to me like the Cucumber stuff belongs in Rails-land ... but going the other way (and storing it with your JS repo) doesn't seem horrible to me either, just potentially more problematic.

Comment: +1 because your advice is solid, but just to bring a secret option C to the table, why not separate integration tests as its own repository altogether? If software components A and B require common functionality, you would factor it into a dependency C. Shouldn't the same be true when C depends on A and B?

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  It does mean having to maintain yet another repository, but then again if you're already splitting code in to two repositories then maybe a third isn't much more work?  Certainly a reasonable alternative to my suggestion.